# Confusing logic of dp

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve a dynamic programming question on [hackerearth](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/introduction-to-dynamic-programming-1/practice-problems/algorithm/rhezo-and-prime-problems/description/).
Even after trying to simulate the logic using pen and paper, I am unable to comprehend the solution (given in the [editorial](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/introduction-to-dynamic-programming-1/practice-problems/algorithm/rhezo-and-prime-problems/editorial/)).
Can someone explain the commented lines? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been trying to understand it for 3 days...

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
const int MAXN = 5e3+5;
bool vis[MAXN];
int ar[MAXN];
int pre[MAXN];
vector<int> v;
int dp[MAXN];
void sieve() {
    v.push_back(2);
    for(int i=3;i<MAXN;i+=2) if(!vis[i]) {
        v.push_back(i);
        for(int j=i*i;j<MAXN;j+=2*i) vis[j]=true;
    }
}
int main() {
    // freopen("TASK.in","r",stdin);    
    // freopen("TASK.out","w",stdout);
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    assert(n<=5000);
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        scanf("%d",&ar[i]);
        assert(ar[i]<=100000);
        pre[i]=pre[i-1]+ar[i];
    }
    sieve();
    dp[0]=dp[1]=0;
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++) {
        dp[i]=dp[i-1];
        for(int j=0;j<(int)v.size() and v[j]<=i;j++) {
            int p=i-v[j]-1;//please explain this line
            if(p==-1) dp[i]=max(dp[i],pre[i]);
            else dp[i]=max(dp[i],dp[p]+pre[i]-pre[p+1]);// please explain this line 
        }
    }
    cout<<dp[n]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Josh Lee I have highlighted the portion which needs explaination.Seems you have not read the entire description so please remove the hold

Comment: Questions should be reasonably self-contained; your question is absolutely meaningless without the pages it links to. What if those pages go down (temporarily or permanently)? What if someone else has the same question as you, and tries to search Stack Overflow to see if it's already been answered? What if someone has limited network connectivity, and doesn't want to risk clicking on your links?

Comment: @ks 1322 seems people donot like answering dp questions

Comment: @coder, please note that posting link to [editorial](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/introduction-to-dynamic-programming-1/practice-problems/algorithm/rhezo-and-prime-problems/editorial/) is useless because it is locked for me and I guess for everyone here.

Comment: @ks1322 my apologies i thought that editorial is open for all , have put the code here hope its fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `array pre`stands for prefix sum, `vector v` contains prime numbers below `MAXN`. First line you have commented is
`int p=i-v[j]-1;`
Here `v[j]` is the `jth` prime number starting from `2`, `dp[i]` is the best possible score for first `i` problems. If you solve `v[j]` number of consecutive problems (from `i` and going backward) you are left with `i - v[j]` problems from the beginning. `-1` comes from the fact that you cannot solve the `(v[j] - 1) th` problem from `i` (backward) (if you do that you will have solved `v[j] + 1`   consecutive problems which is not prime as `v[j]` is prime).

Second line you have commented:
`dp[i]=max(dp[i],dp[p]+pre[i]-pre[p+1]);`
It follows from above since if you solve `v[j]` problems from `i` (backward) you get `pre[i]-pre[p+1]` points and you add that with `dp[p]` which is best result you already obtained for `p`. For example if `i = 10` and `v[j] = 3` you get `dp[10] = max (dp[10],dp[6]+pre[10]-pre[7])` which is what you would expect.

Comment: @ xashru thanks for such a beautiful explaination i was struggling to understand it from 3 days thanks a lot. hope i get my points back